# Ansible variable name `environment` is reserved?

Tags: ansible

I've got a strange situation today. I called one of my variables in a playbook `environment`. If I dump variables using `debug` instruction, it is shown ok

```
   "environment": "development",
```

But if I try to access it from a script using `{{ environment }}` it is always assigned a value of `{}`. I renamed it and it worked ok. Why is that? Is `environment` a reserved name in Ansible? I checked variable dump - there is no clashes with defined vars.

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_environment.html

Comment: @NathanCooper Thats, but that is about a statement named `environment`. Can a variable be named the same as a statement? For example, can we have a variable named `when`?

Comment: No you can't. You have to choose another name. Been there, got bitten too. `env` ?

Comment: @leucos Was scared to use `env` too ;) Chose `env_name` ;))

Comment: Yes, you're right to stay on the safe side ;) I will let @NathanCooper answer since he gave the answer first.

Comment: @leucos Thanks ;) BTW, so strange that Ansible doesn't complain about you choosing reserved words as a variable names. This could be easily checked by playbook linter. Will file an issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a statement regarding `environment` in the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/fP0hX2Za4I0/nF7cY8RkCwkJ):

> Yes, environment is a restricted keyword. Initially specific within
>   playbooks, but it gets injected in the runner:
>
> ```
> inject['environment'] = self.environment
> ```
>
> so it will erase whatever value was set by inventory of vars.

There is a yet unaddressed [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4816) to warn if reserved variables are used.

Comment: Thanks! So, can we have our variabled named after keywords like 'when'? I guess my problem came just from `environment` variable being injected and overwriting mine, right?

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly enough, `Environment` (proper-case) is usable, but `environment` (lower-case) is not as you found out.

I came across this one day when I accidentally used my existing Environment variable specified in lower-case and had a fun time trying to diagnose the issue.

I'd stick to using a different name as well (although I still use `Environment` on purpose just to remind myself about case sensitivity in variable names).