# Unable to fail terminate Ansible playbook upon string match condition

Tags: string, ansible, terminate

I wish to fail and terminate my ansible playbook when `Number=TKT334`

Below is my playbook:

```
---
- name: "Play 1"

  hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: True
  serial: 1
  tags: always
  tasks:
   - name: Setting string variable.
     set_fact:
       inlinevar: '2020-06-10 20:22:16\tTKT334\tKIRAN\tDeployed\tPRODUCTION'

   - name: Setting string variable.
     set_fact:
       environment: 'PRODUCTION'


   - block:
      - name: "Search to avoid duplicate CR Numbers user:{{ ansible_user_id }}"
        shell: "echo SUCCESSSSSSS"
        failed_when: (inlinevar is search( Number ) and environment == "PRODUCTION")

      - debug:
          msg: This is FINAL  inlinevar `{{ inlinevar }}`

     rescue:
      - name: Print custom conditional debug message

        fail:
          msg: >-
            {{
              command_result_app.stdout is search( Number ) |
              ternary(
                "This CR is already Deployed. Hence retry with a Unique CR Number.",
                "The Dtabase is not reachable. Unable to connect To the Database."
              )
            }}
```

However, when I run the playbook I do not fail and continues to print the debug:

I was expecting it to fail but it shows ansible run as successful and does not terminate the playbook executions.

See the output below:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e Number=TKT334
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [Play 1] *************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Setting string variable.] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Setting string variable.] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Search to avoid duplicate CR Numbers user:{{ ansible_user_id }}] ***
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is FINAL  inlinevar `2020-06-10 20:22:16\\tTKT334\\t KIRAN\\tDeployed\\tPRODUCTION`"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`environment` is a special option used to set environment variables for tasks, e.g.

```
- name: Do something
  shell: echo "whatever"
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://my.server.com:8080
    no_proxy: my.domain.com
```

In your case, environment is always empty after `set_fact` and `environment == "PRODUCTION"` is always false.

Rename your variable to something else, don't use environment (see [this other question for more discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014136/ansible-variable-name-environment-is-reserved)), e.g.

```yaml
    [...]
    - name: Setting string variable.
      set_fact:
        deploy_environment: 'PRODUCTION'

    - block:
        - name: "Search to avoid duplicate CR Numbers user:{{ ansible_user_id }}"
          shell: "echo SUCCESSSSSSS"
          failed_when: (inlinevar is search( Number ) and deploy_environment == "PRODUCTION")
    [...]
```